# Asp.net Modal Window Javascript url passing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog, carousel

I have created a script that creates a carousel that slides trough versious images. When i click on a item, a new Modal Window get shown.
The modal window contains a iframe linked to a youtube video.

The problem is that i want to change to url of the desired youtube video based on what a user click in the carrousel.  I can pase the id of the click but i dont know how i have to change the iframe. still a beginner in javascript.

Here is my code

function handleLeftClick(id) {
            var a = $("#testvid" +id).attr('src');
            alert(a);
        };

```
     // When the player is ready, add listeners for finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function () {
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

    function onFinish(id) {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
```

//          $('#myCarousel').carousel('play');
    }

```
function onPlayProgress(data, id) {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
}

// invoke the carousel
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 1000,
    pause: "hover"
});

//Modal Window


$(document).ready(function () {

    /* Get iframe src attribute value i.e. YouTube video url

    and store it in a variable */

    var url = $("#myModal").attr('src');



    /* Assign empty url value to the iframe src attribute when

    modal hide, which stop the video playing */

    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {


        $("#youtubeVideo").attr('src', '');

    });



    /* Assign the initially stored url back to the iframe src

    attribute when modal is displayed again */

    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {

        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);

    });
```

});

$('.activate_modal').click(function(){

```
          //get the id of the modal window stored in the name of the activating element  
          // var modal_id = $(this).attr('name');  


          //use the function to show it  
          //show_modal(modal_id);  
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }); 

</script>
```

×

                    YouTube Video

Comment: Can you post your html please?

Comment: This problem is solved in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem add this in the handleleftClick

```
$(".modal-body").html('<iframe id="youtubeVideo" width="100%" height="350px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src=" ' + a + '?html5=1"; "  allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen ></iframe>');
```